# What is the most correct translation of “nyoi bō” (如意棒), “compliant pole” or “mind stick”?

Tags: translation, anime

The *nyoi b­ō* is the power pole Goku uses to extend it at will and connects Korin Tower to Kami's Lookout.

Answer (score 2):

The 如意棒{にょいぼう} (short for 如意金箍棒{にょいきんこぼう}) is the name of 孫悟空{そんごくう}'s staff from the Chinese folktale 西遊記{さいゆうき}, known in English as *Journey to the West*, which is the inspiration for the Dragon Ball series. The staff itself has an English Wikipedia article on it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruyi_Jingu_Bang), and the name is often translated as "Power Pole" in English-language Dragon Ball media.

Comment: I understand, but I could you please tell me where it comes from the translation "mind stick"?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't think I exactly understand the question.

Are you asking where the term 如意棒 comes from? That's in the original story.

I've never heard "compliant pole" or "mind stick" before.

Comment: @wuerling Technically, the question is asking which of "compliant pole" and "mind stick" is a better translation of 如意棒 and your answer doesn't talk about either. I guess OP came across these translation on pages like [this one](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Power_Pole), where they list a number of "alternate names" for "Power Pole".